# python split string that has both spaces and dash

Tags: python, string, split

I have an iteration that produces the below `string`

```
"always - blue"
"sometimes-yellow - red"
"seldom - blue"
"maybe-red - blue"
"mostly-blue - yellow"
```

What I am trying to do is to split up the string by `" - "`

**Desired Result**

```
['always', 'blue']
['sometimes-yellow', 'red']
['seldom', 'blue']
['maybe-red', 'blue']
['mostly-blue', 'yellow']
```

I have tried `a.split("-")`, and `a.split(" - ")` but this seems to split up every occasion that there is a `-`. *i.e.* `['sometimes-yellow', 'red']` is split into `['sometimes', 'yellow', 'red']`. Which is not what I want.

How should I be splitting the string to achieve what I want?

Comment: and why didn't the `a.split(" - ")` work? Also do you want `list`s or `str`ings as output?

Comment: `a.split(" - ")` should work.

Comment: Is your desired result really `"['always', 'blue']"` or is it actually `["always", "blue"]`?

Comment: Sorry. I want it to be in a list output. not string output.

Comment: You can use rsplit('-') for splitting the string in list. string.rsplit(' - ').

Comment: a.split(" - ") does work on your example on my console

Comment: `a.split(" - ")` is working fine.

Comment: Hmm, I closed and open pycharm again to run the code... `a.split(" - ")` seems to work this time round... Which is weird. But i'll try the other suggestions as well just to be safe! :) Thank you all

Comment: @jarryjafery `rsplit('-')` will split `"mostly-blue - yellow"` in three part. probably you have think of this `rsplit(' - ')`.

Comment: You have to give spaces with - as rsplit(' - ') then it will give you your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have simple space characters on either side of the '-' .... either in the subject strings or in the split argument ?
Your editor might be inserting a tab.

Otherwise, the simple split() with your 'space minus space' sequence as arg will do what you want.

My thinking is: "what he has *should* work, so what else could go wrong ?"

```
>>> z = "always-red-xxx-sss - blue"

>>> z.split(" - ")

['always-red-xxx-sss', 'blue']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use rsplit() to split the string in your desired format.

```
>>> string="always - blue"
>>> string.rsplit(' - ')
['always','blue']
>>> string2="mostly-blue - yellow"
>>> string2.rsplit(' - ')
['mostly-blue','yellow']
```